# How to configure WCF to push real-time data to the client?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I need to send live updates from server to client. I know that WCF generally can do this. However silverlight is a picky client..

Does anyone know how to **configure WCF to send the real-time updates to Silverlight client?**

Snipets from configs and walkthrough will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use WCF Callbacks.  A good walkthrough that shows several configurations for this is available on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645027%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).  We used the NetTCPBinding at my last job to great effect.  It's very fast and efficient.  The downside is that it doesn't support secure transport on Silverlight, so if that's a requirement you'll need to go with the PollingDuplexHttpBinding.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the infrastructure (intranet?) you could [use sockets](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/SocketsLight-Silverlight-Sockets-Framework.aspx).

Comment: in the end I built a socket server cos IIS was not possible to install due to admin policies on that particular box... but had to accept another answer as the question was abt WCF. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your WCF service to use [PollingDuplexHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.pollingduplexhttpbinding%28VS.95%29.aspx) .

See [this video tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Duplex-Communication-with-WCF-in-Silverlight-4-Silverlight-TV-34) from channel9.

Comment: PollingDuplexHttpBinding isn't the only valid binding for this setup.  NetTCPBinding can be used as well.  The real issue is that a WCF Callback has to be set up.