# Silverlight - using duplex with PollingDuplexHttpBinding instead of NetTcpBinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight, wcf-binding

I'm building a Silverlight website and I'm looking for the simplest two way communication between the client and the server.

As I've understand, this is done with WCF, using duplex.

I've read some tutorials, all regarding either NetTcpBinding or PollingDuplexHttpBinding.

NetTcpBinding seems a bit simpler in every aspect.

And I wandered, regarding Silverlight applications, what are the drawbacks?

Is there any reason to use PollingDuplexHttpBinding instead of NetTcpBinding?

Comment: This question was answered here:

 - [http://stackoverflow.com/a/5649358/1308645](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5649358/1308645)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a lot of reasons but comparing nettcpbinding with PollingDuplexHttpBinding dramatically affects performance, only solution to use in intranet environment and can use only ports 4502-4534. Again, SSL is not suported by silverlight for nettcp protocol.